# Vaadin Designer installed but can't create Vaadin 10+ design

Tags: eclipse, vaadin, designer

I have installed Vaadin Designer with Eclipse but I can't see "Vaadin 10+ design" in the "New..." wizard. Also there should be a Vaadin tab in Eclipse Preferences but it doesn't.

In installation details Vaadin is showed as Installed. [Eclipse IDE Installation Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5oNy.png)

Installation details :

- Eclipse 2021-12 (4.22.0)
- Vaadin Designer 4.6.15
- Vaadin Plug-in for Eclipse 4.1.6
- Windows 11 64bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed fresh latest Eclipse 2022-03 this time in "C:\Users..." directory instead of "C:\Program Files..." and I can choose Vaadin 10+ design.